# What would a world-ending meteor impact look like from the ground?

Tags: planets, meteor

I've read a lot of questions about the specifics of meteor impacts on this site, but strangely this one seems to still elude me:

Assume a meteor of sufficient mass and speed to wipe out human life *within a week* (if not sooner) impacts the planet. What does this look like from the perspective of a person on the ground? No real change until instantaneous vaporization? Death by a massive shockwave? Localized devastation followed by a slow collapse to environmental causes?

To be specific: from the *moment the meteor is seen by the naked eye* to the *extinction of life on the surface*, and *from the perspective of a human observer,* what happens in what order?

The impact in question happens over land, and at a roughly perpendicular angle; the observer is able to see the impact site at the edge of the horizon assuming they're elevated no more than a storey above flat terrain.

Comment: Do you mean literally look like, as in being observed exclusively visually? Or do you mean more generally what the experience would be like? It would seem to be pretty difficult to, standing on local ground, *see* something that happens on the other side of the planet...

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Naota! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: The *Walking With Dinosaurs* book contains a rather lengthy description of the devastation caused by the meteor impact that wiped out the dinosaurs, but I don't know a) how scientifically accurate it is, and b) whether it fits your definition of "world-ending".

Comment: Wiping out ALL humans within a week it tough. The asteroid has to be a lot bigger than [Chicxulub impactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_impactor)

Comment: More the overall experience than specifically how it would appear visually. Essentially I want to detail the effects of this worst case scenario from a first-hand viewpoint for a bit of flavour content in a game, and need the specifics to do so.

Comment: Well, this can be relevant: [The History of Earth - How Our Planet Formed](https://youtu.be/uHUTbq-j0UU?t=276)

Comment: Here's another relevant link: https://www.lpi.usra.edu/science/kring/Chicxulub/global-effects/

Comment: A bright light, a rushing wind, a brief moment of pain... and then oblivion.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE! Please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour]. I have VTCd as too broad because you're asking for too much. The nature of that impact changes if its on land or at sea, if its over a frozen pole or on the equator, the angle of impact and the exact size of the meteor, etc. What a person sees is likewise varied (ground zero, other side of planet, on mountain, on beach, in office building...). Answering all possibilities is too much. Please narrow this to one specific question.

Comment: Example: What would a person standing on the beach outside San Diego, CA (a sunny, clear day) experience from the moment a 50Km-wide asteroid struck Bangladesh perpendicular to the surface of the Earth at 25Kps?

Comment: Sadly, your query is way too broad! In Stack exchange, you really need to write questions that provide enough background detail to be answerable and you really need to focus on one specific issue or problem.  In this case, you need to define your premise. Basically, in order to nearly instantly wipe out all human life, you're looking at something that will pretty much vapourise the surface of the planet. Specificity is key!

Comment: In such an event, what it looks like would be the least of your problems

Comment: killing the submariners in all the nuclear subs within a week will be very hard,  but not as big as the impact that created the moon.

Comment: Sorry, I'd provide the specific details of the meteor if I knew them, but part of the reason I'm asking is that I'm not certain what amount of force (size, speed, angle of impact) would be necessary to wipe out life on the planet in a way faster than immediate-term ecological devastation.

As for the other conditions I do know, I've added those to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are close enough to see it visually, and you're not in some kind of bunker, you'll die before the information from your eyes reaches your brain.  The infrared and visual light from the impact will cook you instantly.  You might actually even die before the impact, the asteroid itself will be heated to such an extreme degree it may cook you as it flies overhead.

If you ARE in a bunker, you'll see a blindingly bright flash.  Once it dims enough to open your eyes, you will see a huge, white sphere expanding from the impact site at a few times the speed of sound; this is water vapor, condensed out of the air by the shock wave.  If you and your bunker survive the shock wave, you'll see a towering fireball at the impact site, with more meteors streaking away from it; these are rocks from Earth blasted away at hypersonic speeds.  Some of these will fall back to the Earth and cause their own impact events.

Comment: The impactor is unlikely to move at such speed so that it could not be seen before it kills the observer.

Comment: Faster than the speed of light? Feels kind of fast. It was thrilling to read this answer, though.

Comment: This is pretty much how I would have answered it. If you are within the horizon distance and therefore close enough to see the impact itself, you will be killed almost instantly.

Comment: @Alexander If the impactor comes in from the far side of the impact site, it never actually flies over you before it hits the ground.  Imagine if it flies in from beyond the horizon, and hits at the horizon.  It wouldn't cook you then.

Comment: The question states "from the moment the meteor is seen by the naked eye", and to me it implies that naked eye should be in position to observe the meteor.

Comment: @Isaac information does not travel from your eyes to your brain at light speed.

Comment: @Alexander I am saying that if the meteor flies overhead, the heat it gives off as it flies might cook you to death before it lands.

Comment: Interesting - and definitely informative. Thanks!

Comment: If you’re anywhere near the impact site then an asteroid big enough to kill everything (order of km) will crush you and cook you to death before it gets below the cloud layer. The reason being the atmosphere won’t have time to get out of the way and will (very briefly) be subject to some very impressive compressive forces. Nothing to do with the heat of the asteroid: it’s the air that kills you.

Comment: @Alexander: slowest it could reasonably be moving is ~11km/s. That’s 10x faster than most bullets and fast enough to close the gap from the ISS to Earth in 30s or so. Unless you happened to be staring upwards and waiting for it best you’d see is a bright dot.

Comment: @Joe Bloggs meteors are firing up in upper atmosphere. People have tens of seconds to observe them coming down, like it was in case of [Chelyabinsk meteor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelyabinsk_meteor).

Comment: @Alexander: see my point about clouds.

Comment: @Joe Bloggs can you please elaborate on how the air is going to kill? You do realize that asteroid moves with supersonic speed and air at the ground level would stay undisturbed until the very end?

Comment: @Alexander: the air won’t stay undisturbed: the forces involved are such that sonic vs supersonic doesn’t make much difference. The asteroid might outpace it’s own shockwave, but the air *underneath* the asteroid is still being pushed down ahead of the asteroid at a similarly supersonic speed since it physically can’t get out of the way. That front of plasmised air extends ahead of the asteroid.

Comment: @Joe Bloggs Ok, will asteroid's shock wave speed exceed the speed of asteroid itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88838/discussion-between-joe-bloggs-and-alexander).